# App running in Anniversary Update doesn't show CommandBar PrimaryCommands buttons until you select the More (...) menu

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have written an app that works works correctly in Windows 10 builds 10586 and 10240, but not in build 14393 (Anniversary Update).

When running in the Anniversary Update build, the problem is that buttons in my command bar's PrimaryCommands area do not appear. If you show the SecondaryCommands area (by selecting the "**...**" menu on the right end of the command bar), then the buttons in PrimaryCommands magically appear, in addition to the secondary commands. Then the primary command buttons remain visible throughout the remainder of the session as they should.

But this problem only occurs in build 14393. In earlier Windows builds, the CommandBar buttons appear immediately, as they should. You don't have to show the secondary commands to make the primary commands appear.

Note that I am using VisualStateManager (with the `GoToState` method) to set different visibility states for my buttons. Buttons appear or disappear depending on the current context.

The CommandBar component is located in the main app page. In the same page, I also have a Frame in which I load various Pages as the user chooses various navigation options.

I call the GoToState method when the user navigates to a different page (from the Frame's Navigated event), to set the CommandButton visibility states based on the selected page:

```
// Change the visual state of command buttons based on the page selection
string pageType = ContentFrame.CurrentSourcePageType.Name;
var stateFound = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, pageType, false);
```

Here are my visual states, defined in the page's XAML markup:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectedPageStates">

        <VisualState x:Name="ProductsPage">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="CommandDirections.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandShare.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandPrint.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandSettings.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="NewsPage">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="CommandDirections.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandShare.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandPrint.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandSettings.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="MapsPage">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="CommandDirections.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter Target="CommandShare.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandPrint.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandSettings.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="SalesPage">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="CommandDirections.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandShare.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandPrint.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="CommandSettings.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

As I said, the code works fine in Windows builds prior to 14393. But in build 14393, the PrimaryCommands are not visible until the user shows the More (...) menu. I'm wondering what may be different in build 14393 to cause this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with that myself. I think there's a problem in the new `IsDynamicOverflowEnabled` property where it sometimes causes buttons to inadvertently overflow into the secondary commands dropdown. For C++ the fix was to disable that new feature like that:

```
if (Windows::Foundation::Metadata::ApiInformation::IsPropertyPresent(L"Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CommandBar", L"IsDynamicOverflowEnabled"))
{
    this->CommandBar->IsDynamicOverflowEnabled = false;
}
```

The `CommandBar` control seems to have a bug where user code collapsing buttons completely breaks the dynamic overflow logic.

Comment: I tried this using the C# equivalent code (in the Loaded event), but I still had the issue. It got me to thinking, though, that maybe my situation was slightly different because there are scenarios in which my PrimaryCommands area is completely empty. By making it so there's always at least one PrimaryCommand showing, it works. It's not ideal, but it gives me a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I has a same kind of issue.. I update the command bars in c# code when the visual states get changed. Works perfectly on 10240 and 10586. But when running in 14393, when I update the primary commands (clear and add) icons disappear and only labels are shown. Also the overflow button get hidden.

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem, Nuwannnz. The problem I saw happens when you set WindowsTargetPlatformVersion (c++) or TargetPlatformVersion (C#) in the project file to 10.0.14393.0 (or when you set it in project properties). The overflow button does not get hidden, but icons from the `PrimaryCommands` area move to the `SecondaryCommands` area (the overflow). In my case this seems to be related to changing the visibility of the `CommandBar` in `VisualStates`. Can you share a project or code snippet that makes the problem reproduce? I could share it with the controls team.